# Wpf Binding to Visibility of WindowsFormHost

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a WindowsFormsHost whose visibility changes from "Visible" to "Collapsed" and vice versa based on certain triggers.  I also want to be able to bind this "Visibility" to a variable as I need to be able to look at the Visibility field for certain reasons, and I can't just "look" at it because they're in two different projects (the style which holds this WindowsFormsHost is in basically a resources project).

Anyways, I have this:

```
    <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="2" Name="PART_ToggleContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
     Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Source={StaticResource StatusProvider}}"
    >
```

And in the control template parent I have a multitrigger which checks a couple dependency fields and tries to hide the form (and the hiding works).

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <MultiTrigger>
       <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsBeingDragged" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="IsWorking" Value="False" />
       </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
       <Setter Property="IsVisibleDProp" Value="False"/>
       <Setter TargetName="PART_ToggleContainer" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      </MultiTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Here's the binding I use for Visibility, "IsVisible", in the class that gets used as the data provider.

```
private Visibility IsVisibleProperty = Visibility.Visible;  


public bool bIsVisible
  {
   get { return bIsVisibleProperty; }
   set
   {
    if (bIsVisibleProperty == value)
    {
     return;
    }
    bIsVisibleProperty = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
   }
  }
```

The setter isn't hit when the property changes.

Any clues?

I also tried a workaround, to set this "IsVisibleDProp" dependency that resides in the same place as "IsBeingDragged" and "IsWorking", but it never hits the setter either (though I do set the other two programmatically, and IsVisibleDPropis set using the multitrigger).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you intended it to be but your property is named `bIsVisible` and your binding to a property named `IsVisible`

Also make sure the OnPropertyChanged parameter matches the property that is changing so WPF will retrieve the new value from it.